# Find INDEX of tuple match to 1 on 1 and 2 on 2 and so on...But not in 2 on 1 or 1 on 2 using python

Tags: python, indexing, compare, tuples

```
R=[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```

For the above set i need to get the INDEX where the first value should match to the ONLY to the first value of the set  and second should match to the ONLY the second value
which means when i match a[0] to R[tuples] none of the elements in a and R shouldn't be equals to each other other than 1 to 1 or 2 to 2

in simple first should match only to the first and second should match ONLY to the second element in a resulted set. and it cannot match any other element of the result sets

### Expected Answer:

```
a=(2,5) ANS INDEX: (5,7) 
b=(3,6) ANS INDEX: (9,13)
```

Here is my code is going too detail and too lengthy and taking too long to run for my actual project. 
so i gave a sample above pls help me to drive this in a optimistic way.., to achieve the speed.

```
 for j in range(i+1,i+10):
        b=set(Results[j])
        if (len(a&b)==0):

            for k in range(i+10, i+200):
                c=set(Results[k])
                if ( (len(a&c)==0) and (len(b&c)==0) ):

                    for l in range(i+200, i+600):
                        d=set(Results[l])
                        if ( (len(a&d)==0) and (len(b&d)==0)  and (len(c&d)==0) ):

                            for m in range(i+500, i+1000):
                                e=set(Results[m])
                                if ( (len(a&e)==0) and (len(b&e)==0)  and (len(c&e)==0)   and (len(d&e)==0) ):

                                    for n in range(i+1000, i+2000):
                                        f=set(Results[n])
                                        if ( (len(a&f)==0) and (len(b&f)==0)  and (len(c&f)==0)   and (len(d&f)==0)   and (len(e&f)==0) ):

                                            for o in range(i+2000, i+3000):
                                                g=set(Results[o])
                                                if ( (len(a&g)==0) and (len(b&g)==0)  and (len(c&g)==0)   and (len(d&g)==0)   and (len(e&g)==0)  and (len(f&g)==0) ):              

                                                        for p in range(i+3000, XRUN):
                                                            h=set(Results[p])
                                                            if ( (len(a&h)==0) and (len(b&h)==0)  and (len(c&h)==0)   and (len(d&h)==0)   and (len(e&h)==0)  and (len(f&h)==0)  and (len(g&h)==0)):              

                                                                CN=CN+1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you want to do. Can you explain the examples please?

Comment: Why is the first answer not `(2, 5) -> (5, 3)`, given `(1, 5)` meets the criteria?

Comment: Ok for (2,5) i start looking for my first value 2 in R's first elements and can find my 2 in R[5]  and my value 5 is not present in R[5]. Then i move on to the second value 5 and can be seen in R[7]. and none of the R[7] other elements are not equal to my first value 2.

Comment: b=(3,6) ANS INDEX: (9,13)  Now for (3,6) i start looking for my first value 3 in R's first elements and can find my 3 in R[9] and my value 6 is not present in R[9]. Then i move on to the second value 6 and can be seen in R[11]. but cannot take because it have my first value so i move to the  and none of the R[13] other elements are not equal to my first value 3

Comment: I'm trying really hard to understand your criteria but when you have sentences like "and none of the R[7] other elements are not equal to my first value 2.", when `R[7]` is `(2, 5)` I'm very confused.

Comment: @AChampion sorry bro to confusing u so much. and u got my question better than me...yes my samples went wrong for a and see for b=(3,6),

Comment: basically i want match first to first and second to second and third to third and fourth to fourth elements and when first match it should not match to any other elements in both. hope u got it and i'm so so sorry for confusing too too much.

Comment: Can you show a more realistic input and expect output?

Comment: will do give me a sec

Comment: R=[(1,10,14,34),(2,5,19,21),(3,7,31,32),(1,9,12,31),(2,10,11,22),(4,8,14,32),(13,15,19,34),(1,5,15,20),(3,26,19,25),(4,17,18,21)]

Comment: Find for R[0] and R[1] and the answer would be for 0: 4,5,6,7
for 1: 2,5,6,7 

remember each check should go downward in the same order or R.

So for index 1 the next match is its 2nd index hope u got it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Find for R[0] and R[1] and the answer would be for 0: 4,5,6,7 for 1: 2,5,6,7

Answer for R[**0**] : (3, 4, 5, 6, 7) => R[3] has **1**
Answer for R[**1**] : (4, 6, 7, 8, 9) => R[2] and R[5] no Match, R[4] has **2**; R[8] has **19**; R[9] has **21**

> **Data**:
>
> ```
> #         0              1             2            3             4
> R = [(1,10,14,34), (2,5,19,21),   (3,7,31,32), (1,9,12,31),  (2,10,11,22), 
>      (4,8,14,32),  (13,15,19,34), (1,5,15,20), (3,26,19,25), (4,17,18,21)]
> #         5              6             7            8             9
> ```

```
result = []
for i, T in enumerate(R):
    r = []
    for Ii, Tt in enumerate(R[i + 1:], i + 1):
        if set(Tt).intersection(set(T)):
            r.append(Ii)

    if len(r):
        result.append(tuple(r))
    else:
        result.append(None)

print('result:{}'.format(result))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> #               0              1              2       3     4
> result:[(3, 4, 5, 6, 7), (4, 6, 7, 8, 9), (3, 5, 8), (7,), None, 
>         (9,), (7, 8), None, None, None]
> #         5      6      7     8     9
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Oh thank u so much bro...Ton's of thanks.will check it soon and reply if any doubt. Thanks again.

Comment: Answer for R[0]: R[0][0]=R[3][0] , R[0][1]=R[4][1] , R[0][2]=R[5][2],R[0][3]=R[6][3]  (1=1 ,10=10,14=14,34=34 )

Comment: @JohnEbenezer: Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)